# Finding exact values for trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

Finding exact values for trig functions of acute angles.

I have $\sin \theta = 3/5$.

I know that $y = 3$ and $r = 5$.

How the heck do I get $x$ if I don't know the angle?

Comment: what exactly are x,y,r and $\theta$?

Comment: What are $y$, $r$, and $x$? And how is it you "know" $y$ and $r$?

Comment: y is the opposite and r is the hypotenuse.

Comment: @Adam: Then you have a right triangle. Pythagoras is your friend (or should be, if you didn't keep snubbing him...)

Comment: Its been 8 years or so since I have had to us it so it is easy to forgot. That or am an an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $y=3$ and $r=5$, then because (presumably) the triangle is a right triangle with [legs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Terminology) of length $x$ and $y$, and hypotenuse $r$, by the Pythagorean theorem we have that
$$x^2+y^2=r^2,$$
hence
$$x^2+9=25.$$
Thus $x^2=16$, and therefore $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a picture, too.  That makes keeping things straight easy.